# Очень простой вопрос: "не" или "ни"?

Tags: орфография, не-или-ни

Каркас разрушенного двадцатиэтажного дома – чем не смотровая площадка?

Свыше тридцати километров за день – чем ни марафон?

Answer (score 5):

> Каркас разрушенного двадцатиэтажного дома – **чем не** смотровая площадка?
>
> Свыше тридцати километров за день – **чем ни** марафон?
>
> ...“не” или “ни”?

В обоих предложениях нужна частица **"не"**:

*Каркас разрушенного двадцатиэтажного дома – **чем не** смотровая площадка?*

*Свыше тридцати километров за день – **чем не** марафон?*

Answer (score 5):

Здесь имеет место *простое отрицание* с частицей **не**, по поводу которого ставится риторический вопрос. В этом вопросе сформулировано *утверждение с отрицанием* (это **не** смотровая площадка, **не** марафон), которое поставлено под сомнение добавлением вопросительного слова "**чем**" (смысл вопроса: почему сформулированное утверждение могло бы оказаться неверным - *разве* есть на то причина?). Соответственно, заложенное в таком вопросе утверждение с отрицанием сохраняет свою форму с частицей **не**.